# How to pass values within soap body as parameter using requests module

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython, python-requests

I have written the following code which is executing successfully. However, I want to pass `username` as a parameter instead of directly hard-coding within
soap body.

```
import requests

url = "url?WSDL"

headers = {"Content-Type": "text/xml;charset=UTF-8"}

body = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
          <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <tem:Authentication>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:UserName>username</tem:UserName>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:Password>password</tem:Password>
      </tem:Authentication>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:func1>
         <!--Optional:-->
       <tem:incident_number>INC000005215731</tem:incident_number>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:wii>
            <tem:Submitted>false</tem:Submitted>
            <tem:Work_Info_Type>General_Information</tem:Work_Info_Type>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <tem:Summary>test</tem:Summary>
         </tem:wii>
      </tem:func1>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>"""

response = requests.post(url, data=body, headers=headers)
print response.content
```

Also, how can i convert the above code using `suds`?

So far, I have written the following code:

```
from suds.client import Client
import logging

client = Client("url?WSDL")
user = client.factory.create('Authentication')
user['UserName'] = 'username'
user['Password'] = 'password'
client.set_options(soapheaders=user)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
body = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
          <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <tem:Authentication>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:UserName>{username}</tem:UserName>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:Password>{password}</tem:Password>
      </tem:Authentication>
   </soapenv:Header>"""
response = requests.post(url, data=body.format(username="bob", password="abc123"), headers=headers)
```

You could also use a template engine like django/jinja2 and use context variables.

The proper solution here is to switch to suds instead of requests

https://bitbucket.org/jurko/suds

edit: Zeep is also a good soap library that is faster than suds
http://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/

Comment: I already tried `suds` and I was having debugging issues and that is why I moved back to `requests` i have added some portion of the code using `suds` in original question. can you suggest how to move further?

Comment: What kind of issues are you having? Some detail into your suds issue would be helpful. Is it a public WSDL? Your setup seems similar to what i do except I think soapheaders is a list for me